# RewriteRule no longer working after web host upgrade

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My webhost recently upgraded their PHP to a new version, and now one of my redirects no longer works.

The redirect that doesn't work now is:

```
RewriteRule toppers/i-(.*)/n-(.*).html$ toppers.php?i=$1&n=2
```

Which I find strange because all my other, similar rules still work.

Here is my full .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule toppers/i-(.*)/n-(.*).html$ toppers.php?i=$1&n=2
RewriteRule classes/i-(.*)/n-(.*).html$ classes.php?i=$1&n=2
RewriteRule news/i-(.*)/n-(.*)\.html$ news.php?i=$1&n=2

RedirectMatch 301 ^/cake-topper-pictures-pages/(.*) http://www.caketopper.co.uk/wedding-toppers.php
RedirectMatch 301 ^/cake-topper-picture-pages/(.*) http://www.caketopper.co.uk/wedding-toppers.php
RedirectMatch 301 ^/Cake-Topper-Pictures-Pages/(.*) http://www.caketopper.co.uk/wedding-toppers.php
RedirectMatch 301 ^/feedback-topper-pages/(.*) http://www.caketopper.co.uk/toppers/i-1/n-Couple-on-red-dragon.html
RedirectMatch 301 ^/feedback-toppers/(.*) http://www.caketopper.co.uk/toppers/i-1/n-Couple-on-red-dragon.html

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

What could be wrong and how can I fix it?

---

To varify that it isn't the PHP file, I have tried:

```
echo $topperId = $_GET['i'];
echo $topperName = $_GET['n'];
```

And I get nothing echoed out from the URL.

---

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} toppers/i-(.*)/n-(.*).html [NC]
RewriteRule .* toppers.php?i=%1&n=%2 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} classes/i-(.*)/n-(.*).html [NC]
RewriteRule .* classes.php?i=%1&n=%2 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} news/i-(.*)/n-(.*).html [NC]
RewriteRule .* news.php?i=%1&n=%2 [L,NC]

Comment: Any errors in the error log?

Comment: @jeroen I don't think I have access to it, I don't understand why line 4 wouldn't work if lines 5 and 6 work perfectly?

Comment: If only php was upgraded, the redirect is probably working but there is an error in the php file.

Comment: You ought to delete or comment out that line and try to add a rewrite rule using your webhost control panel directly. Many times they have an API that does it for you with parameters you give it -- hope this proves useful. GatorHost for example has an interface for it; works every time. If this doesn't work, contact the webhost support line

Comment: @jeroen please see the edit, I can confirm it's not the PHP file :(

Comment: did they also upgrade Apache? There were syntax changes in mod_rewrite between Apache 1.3 and 2.0. Not that anyone should have still been using apache 1.3 -- it's wildly out of date -- but if they were on that version, an upgrade will have broken your rewrites.

Comment: Post an incoming URL. Maybe the problem is not in the redirect rules or the script, is the requested URL doesn't hold the information correctly or at all.

Comment: @Felipe Alameda A Here is an example: www.mysite.co.uk/toppers/i-1/n-Couple-on-red-dragon.html

Answer (score 0):

As @jeroen said it is probably the php. Try replacing the whole file with something like

```
<?php
die('Got to PHP');
?>
```

This will find out for sure if you are reaching php. If you have display_errors off and have a parse error or something you could put the code you showed at the top and still get a blank screen.